What makes Christian theism more likely to be true than polytheism?
There are infinitely many combinations of possible polytheisms (2 gods, 3 gods, 4 gods, etc). There are also polytheisms where gods perform different and often complementary functions. What makes Christian theism more likely to be true than all of the polytheistic alternatives?
What specific characteristics show its superiority?

As Plato observed, the difference between theism and polytheism is a matter of category, not number.  The gods of polytheism are finite, contingent, conditioned, temporal, and relative.  The God of theism is infinite, necessary, unconditioned, eternal, and absolute.  They are so different that Plato believed that both existed, even if he dismissed the polytheistic gods as daimons that did not affect philosophy.

What is meant by "more likely"? Likely that it is actually true; likely that someone inventing a religion would choose it; likely that someone would choose to believe it rather than another; likely that …?

How is "Christian theism" classified, as 1 god (unitarian), 2 (binitarian), or 3 (trinitarian), or …?

@Mary has got the point. It's interesting that traditionally polytheistic worldviews all across the world seem to converge on a Plato-style monotheism if anyone tried to get philosophical, e.g. Hinduism, Daoism, or Varro-style Roman paganism all see the many gods as subordinate emanations from one ineffable uncreated divine principle.

And if you define "god" the way these religions do, then Christianity is also polytheistic, as they would call our angels "gods"

By saying 'more likely' this falls into matter of opinion. The nature of Deity cannot possibly be known, unless Deity reveals himself. That humans speculate about deities goes without saying. The question is (or, rather, should be) what speculations should be rejected in order that we may (in this short and unceretain life) focus fully upon what God has revealed about himself ?

Basically, as Mary has conveyed, if one entertains multiple God's, one's God's are too small.

@DarkMalthorp with one important caveat, Christianity never worships (offers sacrifice) to the angels.

@eques  If you are defining them according to their own natures as opposed to whether humans worship them, angels and pagan gods are certainly the same category of being.  There have certainly been Christians who held that the gods were (fallen) angels.

@Mary I was responding to the comment above that "if you define gods the way these religions do, Christianity is polytheistic". i.e. there is some similarity to how the pagans describe gods and how Christians define angels (although some metaphysical differences too) but the key difference is that the pagans worship the gods with sacrifices (cf. Augustine's City of God)

@eques  That's not a difference between angels and gods but in human reactions to them.  There were many pagans who did not worship this god or that one -- because the cult was foreign, or their sphere was not of interest -- would you say that pagan didn't consider them gods?

@Mary That is still a relevant difference. We can talk about difference of natures, but we can also talk about differences of relations, acts and habits. Christianity isn't polytheistic precisely because even if our angels are similar in nature to how the pagans describe their gods we do not give sacrificial worship to any of them.

@Mary or in other words, I wasn't saying anything about whether the pagan gods were the same type of being as angels. You raised that as though it was contrary to the point I was raising.

@eques  I assumed your comment was relevant to the post.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

So many comments, but no answer. This question should be in philosophy SE. But I answered anyways. Also you are technically asking for an opinion, because all answers will be speculation. If Polytheism was real, it wouldn't matter if it was logical would it? It would be the reality. The reason christianity is superior is because it also is reality.

@ Chess Ice - In order to make  the question more defined, I took the liberty to edit it. (As well as the introduction.) This should remove it out of the danger of being "closed", as merely asking for an "opinion." --- If it is unacceptable, feel free to roll it back.  However, this topic is a very revealing one apologetically! Thanks for bringing it up! Peace.

As pointed out by Plato... if there are many gods and not one. How do you determine ethics? If the many different gods do not agree with each other (and in most polytheistic systems they have their arguments) - how can you rely on the gods to educate you in terms of what is right and what is wrong?
Logically, from that point of view, monotheism makes more sense. At least then there is inherently more consistency in terms of divine teachings.

Another thing that is a problem with Polytheism is that the gods are finite (and often flawed) for example: Zeus will mount anything with (or without) legs, has pride and anger issues, etc. What a great example to live up to right? rolls eyes

Now if we view Theism's god as the ultimate highest most pure possible "Good", then the Christian God is also the best option from a psychological perspective as well.

Aim at the highest possible good that you can conceive of. Having aligned yourself with that good, speak the truth and see what happens. That's the act of faith as whatever the truth reveals is the best of both possible worlds regardless of how it appears to you now. -J.B. Peterson

And as Christians we are literally supposed to be like Christ. To strive to be like God, the ultimate "Good person".
This is logically, socially, morally, ethically, and civic-ly the ultimate best possible result. This is why Christian Theism is superior to polytheism and non-christian Theism.

A complete defense of Christianity vs all other religions in the format of  the SE website is not really a plausible expectation you can have. But this is the very short version where I don't specifically call out the flaws and shortcomings of every single other religion.
Christianity however does reflect what we understand of reality better than other religions. (It has a beginning, for example)

@ Wyrsa - Excellent essay on the benefits of Theism compared to the shortcomings of Polytheism!  But don't we still have  to show that Theism is, alone, true?   (By appealing to the self revelation of God, as the only one true God, from the beginning of time and throughout history, for instance.)

"Christians … strive to be like God" — And Buddhists and Hindus don't?

@RayButterworth Feel free to ask that question, perhaps as a new one. I didn't attempt to answer every possible follow up thought. :)

@raygrant You do have a point, but the question was around "more likely than polytheism" If I were to propose a defense as to why the Christian is the proper one, I would answer differently, and be severely limited by the fact this website is designed for short answers. You've seen some of my answers, they are borderline "too long" for this SE format.

I spent many years studying mathematics and writing computer code.
One thing I learned while implementing mathematical algorithms is that the real world maps nicely into three numbers: zero, one, and many.
If one's code contains any other numbers, it's almost certainly going break or need to be updated from time to time.
In religion, gods tend follow a similar pattern:

atheism: 0
monotheism: 1
polytheism: many

Each of these foundations can remain stable for a very long time (e.g. forever).
A religion with some other specific number of gods is going to have problems.
Eventually, either one or more of them will be killed off, or new ones will be born or created.
If we are conjecturing about a supernatural world that has existed forever, it almost certainly has to fall into one of these three categories,
otherwise it would have long ago transformed itself into one of them.
(There are stable situations containing a fixed number of gods, but to avoid conflicts and complications, to be stable, they would either have to be so identical in personality, knowledge, etc. as to be indistinguishable, or have to be so specialized and interdependent that they could not function without each other nor with an additional member. Either way, it would effectively be monotheism.)

The question asks about "likely to be true".
Truth is always 100% certain, no likelihood is involved.
Obviously people don't agree on what the truth is,
but it would be surprising if the truth wasn't in one of those three categories.

@ Ray Butterworth - Indeed, Truth is absolute.  But fallible human beings have the task of seeking out the truth, exercising critical thinking, weighing the evidence, etc. AND come to the likelyhood that the conclusion of their search was right on! The confirmation or correction by the Holy Spirit is a help in the end. (And the loving Providence of the Father, too)

@ Ray Butterworth - See Ray Grant's answer, where "more likely" yields to "most surely."

Specific Characteristic!The main, specific characteristic of Christian Theism is the Benefit of the believer having an assurance beyond a doubt that this religion is true! And this is because of the repeated Self Revelation of God in human history. The Christian believer's God is more than willing to show Himself real to mankind in a proven, factual way, and this firmly establishes his faith with a peace of mind found nowhere else. More likely is transformed into  most assuredly.
More LikelyConcerning the first part of this posted question, "Why is it more likely?" consider the following. Since "more likely" is left undefined, I will assume that it means more likely to be true.
With that definition, the answer is quite easily answered. It is most apparent in the history of Christianity---and of mankind---that God is a self-revealing God.  Actually, from the very beginning (Genesis of the earth and man's existence) God has communicated with His creation!  If there is anything at all apparent from a reading of the Book of Genesis, it is the fact that God is a talker! Throughout the stories of men and women in different predicaments, God showed up and interacted with them.
Then, in the book of Exodus, it is recorded that God spoke directly to the congregation of Israel at Sinai. And indirectly through Moses. From Mt. Sinai unto the Promised Land, God directed the tribes of Jews, sometimes through "the angel of the LORD".
The subsequent history of Israel is replete with the appearances of Prophets who spoke "the burden of the word of the LORD. Their communications were often written down; hence the "major and minor prophets" in the Tanakh. Sometimes the LORD's messages were encouragement, sometimes correction, sometimes judgmental...but in all times, loving, showing mercy unto the generations of the repentant.
Invisible Became VisibleBut most importantly, God  wrapped Himself in a robe of human flesh, and entered the human race physically and visibly. This is the story of Christmas.

The Holy Ghost shall come upon thee, and the power of the Highest shall overshadow thee; therefore also the holy thing which shall be born of thee shall be called the Son of God. (Luke 1:35)


God, who at various times and in divers manners spoke in time past unto the (Jewish) Fathers by the prophets, has in these latter days spoken to us by His Son, whom He has appointed heir of all things, by whom He made the worlds.Who, being the brightness of His glory, and the express image of His person, and upholding all things by the word of His power, when He had by Himself purged our sins, sat down on the right hand of the Majesty on high. (Hebrews 1:1-3)

Empirically Verified HistoryTake note that the manifestations of God have been done in history, not mythology! (as many polytheistic religions) They have been witnessed, not imagined. They have been verified, not supposed. Not done in secret or in a cave or in the lonesome desert. But Jesus was revealed right smack dab in the heart of a bustling metropolis during the Roman/Greek intellectual era. His miracles were empirically verified, not just envisioned by a mirage. (Note that Apostle Thomas "handled Jesus" among many witnesses. (2 Peter 1:16, 1 John 1:1-3, Luke 24:36-43)
The invisible became visible for a short period of time, and fully revealed the nature and character of God's personhood. Yes, God revealed Himself as a person.  He is not a Principle,, not an Ultimate Ideal, He is a person.
And He is not polytheistic. Hear o Israel, the Lord our God is one LORD! (Deuteronomy 6:4) has always been the decree of the Judeo-Christian.
One God, Three ManifestationsWhat some call the Trinity (Tri-unity) is not a declaration of three gods. The one God is manifest in three ways to earthlings. Consider the essence of water manifest as ice, liquid, and steam as a meager illustration. (St. Patrick used the clover leaf as an illustration.) Consider also the one sun that is manifest to earth as heat and light; which in the same way represents the manifestation of the Father to earth as the Holy Spirit (heat), and the Son (as light); yet there is only one sun (Father God).
Most SurelyBecause the Theistic God has revealed Himself continually to mankind, it far supersedes any conclusions about God that emanate from the mere thinking of men, or a man (guru, imman, buddha, council, university etc.).
The machinations, suppositions, ideologies, ad infinitum, don't hold a candle to the Light of the Self-Revelation of God.
Note the personalities of the polytheistic gods (Indian, Hindu, Roman, Greek, etc.)  Most are demigods with mortal propensities and human foibles, representing the worst in human conduct! The one true God is indeed, loving, merciful, gracious...but He is also a God of justice. His anger is a righteous anger against evil; His impatience is with the unrepentant and stubborn; His punishment is the ultimate in justice.
Yes, it is most assuredly (much more than "more likely") that the one God of the Judeo-Christian religion is the true God. Theism rocks! We have God's word on it!

Thus saith the LORD to His anointed, to Cyrus [King of Persia]...for Jacob my servant's sake, and Israel my elect, I have even called thee by thy name; I have surnamed thee though thou hast not known Me.I am the LORD, and there is none else. There is no God beside Me; I girded thee...that they may know from the rising of the sun, and from the west, that there is none beside Me. I am the LORD, and there is none else. (Isaiah 45:1, 4-6)


To whom will you liken Me, and make Me equal, and compare Me, that we may be like?They lavish gold out of the bag, and weigh silver in the balance, and hire the goldsmith; and he makes a god---they fall down, yea, they worship.They bear him [idol of a god] upon the shoulder, they carry him, and set him in his place, and he stands. From his place shall he not remove! Yea, one shall cry unto him, yet he cannot answer, nor save him out of his trouble!Remember this, and show yourselves men; bring it again to mind, o ye transgressors.Remember the former things of old, for I am God and there is none else. I am God and there is none like Me, declaring the end from the beginning, and from ancient times the things that are not yet done, saying, My counsel shall stand, and I will do all I desire to do. (Isaiah 46:5-10)

Contrast in BenefitsOnce the fact of the existence of the One True God is established, it is quite evident what the major Benefits are. One cannot "compare", but only "contrast" them, because they are worlds apart in magnitude. A simple contrast of the abilities of a living God with the inanimate polytheistic gods, represented by idols of wood and gold and stone placed in cold, stone temples, tend to confirm the belief in the superiority of Christian Theism with its Self-revelation, and show it as "most assuredly" the true religion to worship.
The deeds of a living God!The many manifested deeds of a Living God in...

showing compassion...

answering prayer...

protecting from temptation...

supplying provision...

giving purpose in life...
-forgiving the heavy debts of sin...

teaching principles of life...

restoring broken dreams...

healing diseases...

casting out evil spirits...

raising the dead...

ad infinitum...far out-weigh the inabilities and failings of inanimate idols which are the creations of mortal man---idols that have eyes but do not see, that have ears but do not hear, that have mouths but do not speak.



I an Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the ending, who is, and who was, and who is to come, the Almighty!I am He that lives, and was dead (crucified), and behold, I am alive forevermore, Amen; and have the keys of hell and death. (Revelation 1:8, 18)


This seems to be an argument that the Christian God is superior to the multiple Gods of some specific polytheistic religions. It is simply a single specific example, not a proof of the general claim. Can you prove that no possible form of single god could ever be worse than Hinduism? ¶ Even if you could, it doesn't mean that something must be true simply because it is better than all the alternatives.

Validity of Truthfulness - Monotheistic Christianity is "true", not simply because it seems better than alternative polytheistic religions, but because the "self-revealing God" throughout history declares (reveals to mankind) that it is true! We have God's word on it!

So your argument is that Hindu gods have never claimed to be true?

Or more generally, your argument is that in a universe where multiple gods are possible, it is impossible for them to declare that they are true?

@ Ray Butterworth - We deal, not with possibilities, but actualities. God self-revealed Himself in history.  And, by the way, it is impossible for there to be two infinite gods. Overlapping infinities  are not logical in reality.

The OP's questions is "What makes Christian theism more likely to be true than all of the polytheistic alternatives?" and "What specific characteristics show its superiority?".
— Your answer is essentially that Christianity is more likely to be true because it is true, and that all others must therefore be false. Everything else in the answer is more or less irrelevant to this simple logic. You are proving something is true by assuming it is true.

@ Ray Butterworth - Assuming? Nay. Upon researching the reliable manuscript evidence (internal and external tests), it is reasonable to accept its historical statements of the Bible (Tanakh) as accurate.  And those statements record the decrees of the self-revealing Go.  And this God has shown Himself to be "One", (Deuteronomy 6:4, Isaiah 46:9)!  No circular reasoning here.

Yes, but the argument is basically: 1) research and evidence shows that the Bible is correct; 2) Therefore the chance of monotheism being correct is 100%; 3) Therefore the chance of polytheism or atheism being correct is 0%. If #1 really is true, it's a perfectly good argument. 90% of the current answer is irrelevant to that argument, so why not get rid of it and present the short and simple answer?

Now you've added stuff about idol worship. If you're saying that polytheism requires idolatry, it doesn't, and if you aren't saying that, what's the point of introducing idol worship to the answer? ¶ Similarly you're talking about a "living god". If you're saying that polytheism requires non-living gods, it doesn't, and if you aren't saying that, what's the point of mentioning it (much less using it in an attempt to prove something (I'm not sure what though))?

@ Ray Butterworth - Even tho Buddhism is atheistic, it has an idol.  Polytheistic Hinduism has idols.  Islam is not polytheistic.  Judaism is not polytheistic.  Central American polytheism has idols. Egyptian religion has many idols. Also the Greeks.
